# Jquery on Wordpress Frontend not woorking

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Maybe I am so noob with jQuery but cant reach my objective. I need to add the attribute `target="_blank` to all the links inside certain divs. But anything I do works.

I have checked for jquery loaded with:

```
if(wp_script_is('jquery')==false) {
     wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
}
```

Using the the following code nothing happens:

```
jQuery("#adagal").html("<p>asdf*</p>");
```

The `#adagal` element remains with previous content. I have checked in the source if my javascript file was correctly added, and it is.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/AdManagerAdagal/js/ads/show_ad.js?ver=4.3.1'></script>
```

So, what is the problem¿?

Comment: Have you looked at console?

Comment: No errors. Nothing showed at console.

Comment: The js is in the source, and I enqueued jquery with wp_script_is('jquery')==false. Maybe I need something more?

Comment: I found the issue, its needed to put the code inside jQuery(document).ready(function() {} )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
$(".your_class a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Don't forget $ in ready(function to use jquery in your js